# Flutter Scaffold All Page Blurred With Condition

Tags: flutter, dart

What I want to do is I want to blur the whole page when the app like Whatsapp is inactive, I couldn't find any document on how to do this.

```
Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: MyWidget(),
        ),
      )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of `ImageFiltered` class above your Scaffold to achieve this.

```
ImageFiltered(
  imageFilter: showBlur
      ? ImageFilter.blur(sigmaY: 4, sigmaX: 4)
      : ImageFilter.blur(),
  child: Scaffold(),
)
```